# Terminating app due to uncaught exception: 'An instance of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing, xcode6.3

I have created button and i have given action on button
In action

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But whenever i click on the button it gives me this exception even after using ARC in  my project .
I am stuck at this point from last two days So if somebody knows solution please help me.
Thanks in advance.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x16c81e00 of
>   class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still
>   registered with it.

```
Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x15e209d0> (

<NSKeyValueObservance 0x15d0d180: Observer: 0x15e28190, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x15d0d110>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x15d0bef0: Observer: 0x15e21e90, Key path: contentSize, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x15d0c3f0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x15e209f0: Observer: 0x15e21e90, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x15d0d110>
)
```

Comment: have you added any observer in your controller?

Comment: If you're doing KVO, removeObserver when the object is removed from the screen for example, depends on how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have set certain observer for different event..

For e.g. a property change to tableview code will look like :

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil]
```

You need to remove all those observer in dealloc method like :

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.tableView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"]; }
```

Comment: When i am using ARC in my project then it will not allow me to use dealloc in my project

Comment: is there any other reason do you know why this error occurs.

Comment: Are you using any observer in your application?

Comment: yes I am using and also i have deallocated it as you told but still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76950/discussion-between-nilesh-patel-and-pradumna-patil).

Comment: Do one thing like, Put a break point over there & see that is called properly or not..

Comment: Thank you i was doing same mistake but finally it solved by your help thank you for your time.